# Nuget package install error -- Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm using NuGet within Visual Studio 2017 to try to install a package on an older Web Forms project, and it is failing with the following error:

```
Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed
```

This only happens when trying to install the package on a website that is mapped in IIS (other types of projects work fine), so the project name is http://localhost..., etc., which is what I think it's having trouble parsing. It worked fine until just a few days ago and I'm not sure what caused it to change. Here is the full message I am receiving:

```
Resolved actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'
Found package 'Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3' in 'd:\packages'.
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' already exists in folder 'd:\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' does not exist in project 'http://localhost:89/'
Executing nuget actions took 71.95 ms
Failed to add reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
     Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.
```

Another related clue is that when I open "Manage NuGet Pacakges..." on the website project, it is not showing anything as being installed, even though the packages.config file clearly exists in this project with several references defined.

My environment is as follows:

Visual Studio Professional 2107 Version 15.5.2,
Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.7.02556,
NuGet Package Manager Version 4.5.0, and my NuGet repository is set to install in D:\packages

Does anyone have any advice on what setting I might be able to change to get this working again?

Comment: According to the error, have you checked the nuget packages folder into the source control? If yes, please remove packages folder from TFS, it's not recommended to keep packages in source control. If you are not add packages folder into source control, try to repair your Visual Studio.

Comment: I have the same issue with VS Community 15.5.2. Also if I now right-click on my solution then Add > Existing Web Site... no window opens. See also this related thread and Terry Hughes comments [Developer Community] (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167181/update-1551-nuget-does-not-work-anymore-on-my-solu.html).

Comment: If possible, please have a look at this known issue:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165970/nuget-fails-for-website-projects-hosted-on-local-i.html

Comment: Modifying the solution file as suggested here seems to work, but that's more of a hack than a long-term solution. We have a ticket open with Microsoft and hope they get the issue resolved on their end. Thank you all for you help.

Comment: i have the same problem with 15.5.7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NuGet does not appear to be working for local IIS Web Site projects in VS 15.5.1 to 15.5.5 (inclusive).

The workaround is:

1. Close VS
2. (Just in case) make a backup copy of the .sln (solution file)
3. In a text editor open the .sln file and find the line:

`Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "http://www.devsite.com", "http://www.devsite.com", "{A8837508-9BC1-482A-86EF-4B3156CAFDBE}"`

4. Amend the second parameter and save:

`Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "http://www.devsite.com", "DevWebsiteFolderName", "{A8837508-9BC1-482A-86EF-4B3156CAFDBE}"`

5. Open your solution.
6. Use NuGet as you wish :-)

Optional:

7. Close VS
8. Reverse your .sln change.
9. Open VS

For credit and further reference:

[NuGet fails for website projects hosted on local IIS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165970/nuget-fails-for-website-projects-hosted-on-local-i.html)

[Nuget looking in wrong location for packages.config in web forms web site running on IIS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167040/nuget-looking-in-wrong-location-for-packagesconfig.html)

Comment: Thanks for this useful tips.

Comment: I have the same problem with 15.5.7

Comment: Great tip. If you wonder what value for `"DevWebsiteFolderName"`, just do `"."`.

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me nuts... I spent hours trying to install the Authorize.net nuget package in VS2017 and it kept throwing the same error.

I finally opened my project up in VS2015 and installed it without any issues.

Hope this helps.

- Jason

Comment: Your solution may work for someone. But everyone wants to know if that is the case, what is the reason behind package not going to be installed on VS2017

Answer (score 2):

Given that we haven't gotten any help from Microsoft on this, we've adopted the convention of doing something like what Barry Kaye suggested, but for the second parameter, just replacing it with a single period "."

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be fixed in 15.6.0.  Try upgrading to that version, if you can.

Comment: Tested and confirmed to be working in 15.7.2

Although you may have to uninstall and reinstall the Nuget package as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I solve it this way:

`Right-click on the project -> Properties -> Debug -> App URL`

(The app URL was not the correct one)

[image]